# How to disable use of special php functions on a subdirectory with suhosin extension?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, concrete5, suhosin

I have a Website using Concrete5.

I need to allow the client to access the subpage domain\blocks.

The problem is that if the person with this permissions create a Block and put some code like:

```
file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\somefile.php');
```

He will get the source code the the website.

I am trying to use the suhosin extension to block some functions:

In php.ini

```
suhosin.executor.func.blacklist = ""
```

In httpd-xampp.conf

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/blocks">
     php_admin_value suhosin.executor.func.blacklist "opendir, file_get_contents, phpinfo"
</Directory>
```

The problem is that this is not working. 
Since Concrete5 use a index.php to manage all the url connections.

Basicly when a call to url: www.domain.com/somepage/title;
This is just an example, what actually is called is:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php/somepage/title
```

Then concrete5 translate that into the CMS and eventualy calls the block code.

Since the call is to the root of the domain, it has access to all php functions.

I just want to protect the rest of the website.

Comment: Interesting (and valid) question. You're right, everything is run via the root /index.php, so that's the "origin file" (i'm not very familiar with suhosin). And obviously lots of legitimate c5 code requires opendir/etc. Three points. 1) Which block allows people to enter raw PHP? Nothing distributed with the core. Just don't install that block, or prevent the user from installing blocks. 2) If you mean PHP entered via web admin, that's being exec'ed. Block that. 2) The index.php file is similar to wordpress and others. See if there's a best practice for them.

Comment: I just looked at suhosin. Apparently you can blacklist functions that are `exec()`ed. I assume that was your main worry?

Comment: Not exacly, The problem is that i need to give permissions to the client ( business that buyed the website ) to access the Blocks Folder. So he can create how many blocks he want. My concern is that if he create a block with malicius code, he can hijack code from other areas. Like the eCommerce code. That is the part i want to block.

Comment: So you want to give the *site owner* access to add blocks (folders) (presumably via FTP) to the `/blocks` folder, but you want to put in place controls to prevent access to other blocks, presumably in the same root directory that they have FTP access to? That's much harder, and I'm not even sure why you'd want to do that. But making them non-writable by the web user might be a start.

Comment: I am using FileZilla, so the Ftp part is very simple to block.
The main problem is that if the php inside the block is something like. echo file_get_contents("../controller/page.php") then he will have the source of that file. I can't block the use of file_get_contents because concrete5 use it for some things in the core.

Comment: Can't think of a good solution for you. Unless you have a particularly sensitive use-case that you're not sharing (which is fine...), you're overthinking this. You can set up filesystem permissions to disallow writing outside of most directories; C5 is open-source; the "malicious code" (ie, reading source) has to be uploaded via FTP, so that means "admins" (in some sense of the word). And, most of all, I don't see a good solution, nor do I think one is possible without creating some custom version of suhosin or the like.